# What methods can be used to format an equation into a C# Form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, formatting, equation

Let's say I made a simple string like: `string str = "a/(b^2)"`. I want this expression to be rendered on a form in a convenient format instead of plain text. What methods can be used to approach this?

Here is a screenshot taken from a Microsoft Word document that shows how would a **formatted** equation look like.
[image: Expected result]

Now of course I am not looking for this particular equation as I will need many other custom equations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [AngouriMath](https://github.com/asc-community/AngouriMath/tree/master) which is an open source symbolic algebra library.

Also there is [Math.NET Symbolics](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/). It is a basic open source computer algebra library for .Net.

Comment: Hi Denis, thank you for your time answering this. I took the time and tried both options. It seems like Math.NET Symbolics has the potential to be what I need. However, I tried playing around with it but couldn't find what a way to format equations. But there is a lot in that package to be explored. Do you know if there exists a guild for Math.NET Symbolics that I can read so I am not blindly exploring its abilities?

Comment: Math.NET Symbolics has the [Getting started](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/) page with some examples. And you can find their [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.net?tab=Newest) quite useful. Also, please take a look at [unit tests](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/blob/master/src/Symbolics.Tests/Tests.fs) for this library, you can find a lot of examples there.

Comment: I just finished reading the links you sent me, and unless I somehow missed it, they didn't mention a way to output a formatted equation to a windows form. I have posted a new question on their Stack Overflow page for this regard. Here is the link for anyone who wants to follow answers and is looking for the same in the future: [How to format an equation into a C# Form using Math.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847660/how-to-format-an-equation-into-a-c-sharp-form-using-math-net)